# Add double slash to a path

Tags: java, regex

The method `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns something like this:

```
C:\Users\myuser\path
```

But in my program I need to have double slash, like this:

```
C:\\\Users\\\myuser\\\path
```

Is there a simple way to add these double slashes?

Comment: That looks like a triple slash

Comment: Why do you need that? It looks like a XY problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.replace` function.

```
System.out.println("C:\\Users\\myuser\\path".replace("\\", "\\\\"));
```

ie,

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("\\", "\\\\"));
```

Update:

```
String s = "C:\\Users\\myuser\\path";
System.out.println(s.replace("\\", "\\\\\\"));
```

Output:

```
C:\\\Users\\\myuser\\\path
```